# Opencv Homography matrix H and Inverse H to transform a point is not getting expected results

Tags: python, opencv, transform, perspective, homography

I am using Opencv python interface and got the homography matrix H. It seems to work properly as I can use warp perspective to get warped image from the source image. I now tried to use H and Inverse H to transform a point (not image) back and forth between the two coordinates and is not getting the expected results.

To get the matrix, I did this:

```
pts1 = np.float32(corners)
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0], [400,0], [400,400], [0,400]])
self.transform_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
```

Given this matrix, I use the following to do a forward and inverse transform:

```
def transformPoints(self, x, y, reverse=False, integer=True):

        if reverse == False:
            H = self.transform_matrix
        else:
            val, H = cv2.invert(self.transform_matrix)

        # get the elements in the transform matrix
        h0 = H[0,0]
        h1 = H[0,1]
        h2 = H[0,2]
        h3 = H[1,0]
        h4 = H[1,1]
        h5 = H[1,2]
        h6 = H[2,0]
        h7 = H[2,1]
        h8 = H[2,2]

        tx = (h0*x + h1*y + h2)
        ty = (h3*x + h4*x + h5)
        tz = (h6*x + h7*y + h8)

        if integer==True:
            px = int(tx/tz)
            py = int(ty/tz)
            Z = int(1/tz)
        else:
            px = tx/tz
            py = ty/tz
            Z = 1/tz

        return (px, py)
```

Now, if I do this:

```
s, t = 100,200
print "s=%d, t=%d" % (s,t)
a, b = pt.transformPoints(s,t)
print "a=%d, b=%d" % (a,b)

c, d = pt.transformPoints(a, b, True)
print "c=%d, d=%d" % (c,d)
```

This is what it prints:
a=395, b=169
c=91, d=226

I was expecting c=100 and d=200, or at least something close.

This is the matrix and it's inverse.
H matrix

```
[[ -1.01486350e-01  -1.99156329e+01   8.44058060e+02]
 [  1.82486862e+00   3.62765073e-01  -1.49259809e+03]
 [ -4.43678849e-03  -4.28012674e-02   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Inverse:

```
[[  4.13378829e-01   1.05495739e-01  -1.91452995e+02]
 [ -3.12201095e-02  -2.37099792e-02  -9.03788455e+00]
 [  4.97814178e-04  -5.46754880e-04  -2.36269358e-01]]
```

I tried to do a dot product, and it seems to generate an identity matrix ok:

```
[[  1.00000000e+00   1.77635684e-15  -5.68434189e-14]
 [ -6.93889390e-18   1.00000000e+00   5.32907052e-15]
 [ -2.16840434e-19   1.73472348e-18   1.00000000e+00]]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if A*B is identity the A and B indeed ARE the inverse of each other.

Comment: guess: numpy uses x,y indexing instead of row,col indexing. can you try h0 = H[0,0]
        h1 = H[1,0]
        h2 = H[2,0]
        h3 = H[0,1] and so on?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  If I print h0, h1, ... individually, they are the right elements from the matrix, so I don't think this is the issue though.

Comment: please try with integer = false... you transform and round your resulting points to int precision. then you expect the rounded points to inversely transform back to your original points which is nonsense...

Comment: please try t=200 print "s=%d, t=%d" % (s, t) (a,b) = pt.transformPoints(s, t, False, False) print "a=%d, b=%d" % (a,b) (c,d) = pt.transformPoints(a,b, True, False) print "transformPoints = %d, %d" % (c,d) and post results

Comment: s=100
    t=200
    print "s=%d, t=%d" % (s, t)
    (a,b) = pt.transformPoints(s, t, False, False)
    print "a=%d, b=%d" % (a,b)
    (c,d) = pt.transformPoints(a,b, True, False)
    print "transformPoints = %d, %d" % (c,d)  Generates:s=100, t=200
a=394, b=356
transformPoints = 1441, 942  .  Note that I manually click the 4 points to get the matrix so it may be different than my previous example, but the errors in the generated number doesn't make sense.  Initially I thought it was rounding error, hence I added the integer flag, but it appears not too matter much.

Comment: in your initial sample, the result (91,226) isnt so far away from expected (100,200) and I'm very sure that comes from feeding rounded points to the inverse transformation. In your latest result it looks like you switched the order of "inverse" and "integer" parameters and transformed two times non-inverse with integer precision...

Comment: I was searching and I found another way to do this with cv2.perspectiveTransform.  This gave me the expected response:   def transformPoints2(self, x, y, reverse=False):

  src = np.array([((x, y), (0, 0))], dtype=np.float32)

  if reverse == False:
   cvt = cv2.perspectiveTransform(src, self.transformMatrix)
  else:
   (_, I) = cv2.invert(self.transformMatrix)
   cvt = cv2.perspectiveTransform(src, I)

  #print cvt
  return (cvt[0][0][0], cvt[0][0][1])          Results:  s=100, t=200
a=391, b=556
transformPoints2 = 100, 200     So there must be something wrong with the way I did it originally

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in second line

```
tx = (h0*x + h1*y + h2) 
ty = (h3*x + h4*x + h5) 
tz = (h6*x + h7*y + h8)
```

`h4` should be multiplied with `y` coordinate

Comment: this could be it.  Thanks for spotting it, has been nagging me for a while.  I haven't yet tried it out but very likely will solve the problem.